# How to make a function method which filter and map specific data to render from an object from db

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app I need to fetch some data and from that data I'm getting something called events.

Similar to this

```
[
  {
    "id": "36",
    "ownerId": "",
    "ownerType": "",
    "title": "",
    "body": null,
    "type": "APPOINTMENT_SLOT",
    "typeId": null,
    "startTime": "2020-10-20T09:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2020-10-30T15:00:00.000Z",
    "status": "CREATED",
    "actors": null,
    "eventTemplateId": "8",
    "timezone": null,
    "activeInfo": {
      "active": true,
      "startsIn": 1359,
      "endsIn": 13400,
      "__typename": "EventActiveInfo"
    },
    "__typename": "Event"
  },
  {
    "id": "99",
    "ownerId": "",
    "ownerType": "PARTICIPANT",
    "title": "",
    "body": null,
    "type": "APPOINTMENT_SITE",
    "typeId": "123",
    "startTime": "2020-10-22T08:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2020-10-22T09:00:00.000Z",
    "status": "BOOKED",
    "actors": null,
    "eventTemplateId": "4",
    "timezone": "Europe/Stockholm",
    "activeInfo": {
      "active": false,
      "startsIn": -1461,
      "endsIn": 1520,
      "__typename": "EventActiveInfo"
    },
    "__typename": "Event"
  },
]
```

from above I need to filter specific data from the following part first from the ownerId

- OwnerId
- startTime
- endTime
- ownerType
- type

What I did initially was creating a filter method

```
events.filter(
      event =>
        event.ownerId === participant.studyId &&
        event.ownerType === 'PARTICIPANT' &&
        event.type === 'APPOINTMENT_SLOT' &&
        event.startTime,
    );
```

What I need to achieve is that I have from the new filtered part take the most recent data of an upcoming APPOINTMENT_SLOT and it's endTime.
From here I have to render a button which contains a text plus the ID of the event and that ID changes when the event finished and taking the ID of the next event.

As an example:

event 1 is from 20 Okt to 28 Okt and the button should show as

```
appointments {APPOINTMENT_SLOT ID}
```

The APPOINTMENT_SLOT ID is of the upcoming event/actual event.

event 2 will be the same but when Event 1 is finished the ID of event 2 will be shown and so on

My issue is to make this part correctly as I'm new to react and not sure the best way of doing it I tried a useEffect as example from another code

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(events)) {
      const _appointmentSlots = events
        .filter(
          event =>
            event.ownerId === participant.studyId &&
            event.ownerType === 'PARTICIPANT' &&
            event.type === 'APPOINTMENT_SLOT',
        )
        .map(event => ({
          id: event.id,
          title: event.title,
          start: formatDate(event.startTime),
          end: formatDate(event.endTime),
        }));
      console.log('App_slots', _appointmentSlots);
      setAppointmentSlots(_appointmentSlots);
    }
  }, [events]);
```

Comment: If you want helpful answers to this, please try and remove all irrelevant information from this questions. It's a wall of text right now, but the actual problems seems to be rather simple on first glance.

Comment: Yes sure but what do you think can be removed as irrelevant information just to understand and manage to make a correct question in the edit of it

Comment: As far as I understand, this question is mostly about finding the next slot or something? So I'm pretty sure you can remove the first half and simply start with the filtered/reduced data. As an aside: as long as you're dealing with data, don't format your dates. You'll only want to do that as the very last step, to display them to the user.

Comment: Rereading this, it sounds like you want the next upcoming event from a bunch of them? So just find the one with the closest `startTime`?